# ruby daemons - running but not functioning

Tags: ruby, daemon

I have created my first ruby daemon and it functions fine for about a day but then it stops functioning but it still appears in the /var/run folder.

here is my control code -

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
options = {
 :app_name => "rk_mail",
 :dir_mode => :system,
 :backtrace  => true,
 :log_output => true,
 :monitor    => true
}
Daemons.run(dir + '/mail_receiver.rb', options)
```

I have checked the logs but they dont show any errors

Thanks, alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script will change its directory to "/" when it starts the daemon process.

Here's a way to fix it:

```
current_dir = Dir.pwd

options = {
  :backtrace => true,
  :app_name => "test",
  :log_dir => "#{current_dir}/log",
  :log_output => true,
  :dir_mode => :normal,
  :monitor => true
}
```

This will put the logs inside the log folder that's the same directory as your script.